# The sql statement updates the data in the database, the status field is not updated, even if the compiler shows that the execution is successful

Tags: java, mysql

In my project integrating Mybatis with SpringBoot, I used the same SQL statement to update the data in the database. This SQL statement is normal in other controller methods, but only one controller method needs to change the status field, but it will not be updated. Other fields that are updated at the same time will be updated, At least according to the database connection tool

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible code so that others can help

Answer (score 0):

check the xml file to make sure your mapping of your sql statement and dao

Comment: Of course, the first thing I thought of was the xml mapping, but I have compared it many times. It is worth noting that this sql can be called in other controller methods to change the status field.